# vue-router push route after axios post request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router, typescript-eslint

When I wrote the following code:

```js
axios.post('/user', { email: this.email })
.then(
    (response) => {
      if (!response.data) {
        this.$router.push({ path: '/register', params: { user: defaultUser } });
      } else {
        this.$router.push({ path: '/login', params: { user: response.data } });
      }
    }, 
    (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
);
```

The compiler shows error `@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises: Promises must be handled appropriately or explicitly marked as ignored with the void operator.`

I also tried put a catch block after then block but it's still the same problem.

```js
axios.post('/user', { email: this.email })
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.data) {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/register', params: { user: defaultUser } });
    } else {
      this.$router.push({ path: '/login', params: { user: response.data } });
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I also figured out that the problem disappears when I comment out `this.$router.push`. So the problem might deal with redirecting route and resolving promise. Maybe it's better to rephrase the problem to '**how to redirect route without leaving unresolved promise**'? I hope I make the question clear.

Comment: this should be of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43980188/what-could-this-be-about-tslint-error-promises-must-be-handled-appropriately

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine I have checked the post but I don't think it solved my problem. I've updated the question and hopefully made it clear.

Comment: Is the curly bracket at the bottom of your snippet from an outer function?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Yes that's from an outer function. I made a change and just deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I figured it out. `this.$router.push()` returns a promise which I didn't handle well. The final solution works as the following:

```
axios.post('/user', { email: this.email })
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.data) {
      void this.$router.push({ path: '/register', params: { user: defaultUser } });
    } else {
      void this.$router.push({ path: '/login', params: { user: response.data } });
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Since having `void` would trigger `eslint no-void` syntax error, and I don't care about the return value of this promise, I suppressed the warning by adding `/* eslint-disable no-void */`.